# Recursive Friend routes in React-Router V6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

This React-Router V5 recursive routes example shows exactly what I am trying to achieve: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/recursive-paths

However I am using `react-router-dom@6` and after converting my code to V6 the output is not what I would expect.

```
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function RecursiveExample() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/:id" element={<Person />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

function Person() {
  let { id } = useParams();
  let person = find(parseInt(id as string, 10));

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{person!.name}’s Friends</h3>

      <ul>
        {person!.friends.map(id => (
          <li key={id}>
            <Link to={`${id}`}>{find(id)?.name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      {/* Outlet will render any nested routes */}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

const PEEPS = [
  { id: 0, name: "Michelle", friends: [1, 2, 3] },
  { id: 1, name: "Sean", friends: [0, 3] },
  { id: 2, name: "Kim", friends: [0, 1, 3] },
  { id: 3, name: "David", friends: [1, 2] }
];

function find(id:any) {
  return PEEPS.find(p => p.id === id);
}
```

When following the link to the next person `id` I get the console error `"No routes matched location "/0/1" "`

How can I render these routes recursively while still maintaining the same URL structure as in the V5 example, e.g. `"host.com/1/3/2/..."`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are assuming that the root route is rendering ***nested*** routes (*i.e. a `Route` rendering another `Route` directly*) when actually you are rendering ***descendent*** routes (*a routed component rendering another `Routes` and `Route` components*). By rendering only one route and an outlet, you can't go more than one level deep, e.g. you can render only the root level route, any paths more deep than this don't have any route that matches, e.g. the invariant error you see.

The `Routes` component replaced the RRDv5 `Switch` component, so with understanding that in the RRDv5 recursive paths demo that each `Person` component is rendering descendent routes, the RRDv6 analog is for `Person` to render another `Routes` and recursive `Route` component. The other main difference between RRD v5 and v6 is that in order for descendent routes to be matchable and renderable their parent route necessarily needs to append the wildcard `"*"`, or splat, matcher to the end of its path.

Example:

```
export default function RecursiveExample() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route index element={<Navigate to="/0" replace />} />
      <Route path="/:id/*" element={<Person />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

```
function find(id?: string | number) {
  return PEEPS.find(p => String(p.id) === String(id));
}

function Person() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const person = find(id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{person!.name}’s Friends</h3>

      <ul>
        {person!.friends.map(id => (
          <li key={id}>
            <Link to={`${id}`}>{find(id)?.name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/:id/*" element={<Person />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit recursive-friend-routes-in-react-router-v6]

Comment: Thank you for this very concise answer and for introducing me to the difference between nested and descendant routes!

Comment: @DrewReece One more question, instead of nesting these Person components, say I wanted to just replace the one Person Component being rendered to the last parameter that was navigated to. Eg. exHost.com/friends/0/friends/1 . And have person with the ID of 1 be navigated to. I assume first I would need to remove the routes inside the person component, but what changes would need to be made to the app component for this to work?

Comment: @sebastianwhiffen Sorry, I can't quite follow what you are asking there. Can you clarify?

Comment: @DrewReece I mean to say, Is there a way to maintain the same functionality for the url eg. (exHost.com/friends/0/friends/1/friends/...) but instead of rendering a new people component inside the last one each time a new person is navigated to, now have it replace the person component with the newly navigated person.

Comment: @sebastianwhiffen Am I understanding that you want the *routes* to be recursive/nested, but you ultimately only want to render one single `Person` component for the last person in the path?

Comment: @DrewReece yep, that's what I want

Comment: @sebastianwhiffen Something like this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursive-friend-routes-in-react-router-v6-forked-xtg8ft?file=/src/App.tsx)? Basic gist is to split the `Person` component from the routes it renders, and render `Person` on an index route that exactly matches a path, otherwise render the descendent route a "keep rendering the path" component.